# Is it correct to say "go all the way through the corridor, the elevator is just around the corner"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

You are standing "**in/on**" a corridor (I am not sure we say "**in**" or "**on**" in this case) as shown in the above picture.

**Someone**: **Where is the elevator?**

**You**: **Go all the way through the corridor, the elevator is just around the corner**

Is it correct to say "**go all the way through the corridor, the elevator is just around the corner**"?

Comment: It is definitely "in" the corridor. _You are standing in a/the corridor_. Also, "through" is not appropriate here. We walk through a door, or a hop in through a window. People are more likely to say _Walk/Go all the way down the corridor, the elevator is just around the corner._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are standing in the corridor, you would normally go **along** or **down** it not **through** it.

"go all the way along the corridor; the elevator is just around the corner" is correct, as is "go all the way down the corridor; the elevator is just around the corner"

You could also say "go to the end of the corridor" or "go all the way to the end of the corridor"

Comment: but say, there is a door at the end of the corridor, and the door leads to a garden. Now, you want to go to the garden, then is it correct to say "**go all the way through the corridor to get into the garden**"?

Comment: If you are outside the corridor and need to enter one end, go all the way along and exit at the other end, then you could say "go through the corridor to the garden". If you were in the corridor I would say something like "go along the corridor and through the door at the end"